# Use joins to get data on Rails Database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

There are `users` table and `ratings` table in my DB.

```
=> User(id: integer, created_at: datetime ….)
=> Rating(id: integer, user_id: integer, … created_at: datetime ….)
```

I’d like to know **how many ratings have been created by users who signed up during a certain period on their first day of sign up**.

To get the number of all ratings made by users who signed up that period from now:

```
User.where(:created_at => '2015-07-30'..'2015-08-01').joins(:ratings).count
```

But I don’t know how to exactly get what I want because I want the number of ratings that were made on their first day of sign up.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Using Mysql on Rails

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
User.joins(:ratings).where(created_at: '2015-07-30'..'2015-08-01').group('users.created_at').count
```

returns result in a hash like below -

```
=> {2015-07-14 07:07:10 UTC=>1, 2015-07-16 11:16:09 UTC=>1, 2015-07-17 11:22:05 UTC=>1, 2015-07-17 11:43:17 UTC=>1, 2015-07-17 11:53:12 UTC=>1, 2015-07-28 07:22:44 UTC=>1, 2015-07-28 07:24:57 UTC=>1, 2015-07-28 07:25:52 UTC=>1}
```

Comment: It returns: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, created_at AS created_at FROM `users` INNER JOIN `ratings` ON `ratings`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2015-07-30' AND '2015-08-01' GROUP BY `users`.`created_at``

Comment: edited the `group` call, it should be specific to users table. try now please

Comment: I guess it returns all the values for each user like:

```User.joins(:ratings).where(created_at: '2015-07-30'..'2015-08-01').group('users.created_at').count
   (984.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, users.created_at AS users_created_at FROM `users` INNER JOIN `ratings` ON `ratings`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2015-07-30' AND '2015-08-01' GROUP BY users.created_at
=> {2015-07-30 00:00:00 +0900=>1587,
 2015-07-30 00:00:16 +0900=>202,
 2015-07-30 00:00:22 +0900=>28,
 2015-07-30 00:01:39 +0900=>112,
....```

Comment: it returns `hash` where key is `created_at` date and value is `count`

Comment: Thanks but how can I get just a sum value of all?

Answer (score 2):

You want information about ratings, so the call need to start with ratings, not users. You need an inner join as you only want ratings with a user, and there are conditions on this user. So we need to consult the [rails-guide on joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

And you have a condition that the rating and the user have the same date, this is often easier done as SQL-String-fragment, as it spans two objects and this is difficult to express in Arel.

At last you said you want to count the ratings.

```
Rating.joins(:user).
    where( user: {created_at: Date.new(2015,07,30)..Date.new(2015,08,01)}).
    where( 'DATE(users.created_at) = DATE(ratings.created_at)' ).
    count
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
from /home/guinness/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:112:in `build'

Comment: Well, you have not tolds us how you set up your relation between user and rating. But probably it need to be 'user' instead of 'users' when we talk about the relation (and still users when we talk about the database table, that make it all a little tricky to get right).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
User.joins(:ratings).where("users.created_at BETWEEN ? and ? and users.id = ? ", '2015-07-30', '2015-08-01', current_user.id).count
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns **all the ratings** the users signed in during that period. What I want is not all the ratings but the ratings that were made **on their sign-up date**

Comment: You want to result only for current_user.?

Comment: I want the number of ratings made at 7/30 and by users who signed up at that day

Comment: User.joins(:ratings).where("users.created_at BETWEEN ? and ? and users.id = ? ", '2015-07-30','2015-08-01', current_user.id).count

Comment: Here i supposed current_user is your signed up user, You can modify it accordingly your current_user.id

Answer (score 0):

You can user inner query for this.

```
Rating.joins(:users).where(user: User.where(created_at: Date.new(2015,07,30)..Date.new(2015,08,01))).count
```

Comment: I corrected: Rating.where(user_id: User.where(created_at: '2015-07-30'..'2015-08-01')).count

Comment: but it returns # of all the ratings